# How to find similar documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity

My documents are made up of using various `fields`. Now given an input document, I want to find the `similar documents` using the input document fields. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "ids" : ["12345"],
            "fields" : ["field_1", "field_2"],
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }

}
```

you will get similar documents to id 12345. Here you need to specify only ids and field like title, category, name, etc. not their values.

Here is another code to do without ids, but you need to specify fields with values. Example: Get similar documents which have similar title to: 
elasticsearch is fast

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["title"],
            "like" : "elasticsearch is fast",
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }

}
```

You can add more fields and their values

Comment: Can I specify a document instead of ids? If yes how?

Comment: How to do it if I want to check per field?

Comment: I can't understand, what do you mean by check per field? Do you want to include all fields?

Comment: Say I have a document with 20 fields, e.g. : first name, last name, address, phone number, etc. I want to match per field and get the documents with the highest scores.

Comment: Documentation for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html

Comment: "ids" is no longer supported. This is replaced by "like", which needs an array of an object with "_index" and "_id". Example: "like": [
        {
          "_index": "imdb",
          "_id": "1"
        },
        {
          "_index": "imdb",
          "_id": "2"
        },
        "and potentially some more text here as well"
      ] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-mlt-query.html)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the types of your fields. A general approach is to use a catch all field (using [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html)) with the [more like this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query.

Comment: All fields are text.

Comment: Then the catch all field approach should work well. If you don't want to reindex your docs to create the catch all field, then you can specify all your field names in the "more like this" query.

Comment: Can you provide a toy example? It will be great if you can provide example with boost.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
            "query": {
                "more_like_this" : {
                    "fields" : ["first name", "last name", "address", "etc"],
                    "like" : "your_query",
                    "min_term_freq" : 1,
                    "max_query_terms" : 12
                }
            }

 }
```

Put everything in `your_query` . You can increase or decrease `min_term_freq` and `max_query_terms`

Comment: you can use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html